# spring - why 'redirect' goes to localhost

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using spring mvc for my web application, but redirect acts a little weird.

I have a code adding a user to the database for signup and redirecting a user to another page, but when I deploy it into my server, the redirect keeps looking for 'localhost' instead of the domain name.

here is my code.  It's pretty simple.

```
public ModelAndView register(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
     // does a successful database process.
     return new ModelAndView("redirect:survey1.do?enabled=true&page=0");
}
```

But when it reaches that line, somehow it tries to redirect a user to localhost, even though it is not running locally.

Is it related to any spring configuration?  I used spring framework before a little bit, but I haven't run into this kind of problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced with same issue when spring-boot was behind a proxy. Nginx in my case. You should pass http-header Host from Nnginx to spring-boot. So spring-boot can figure out what is the original URL

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_connect_timeout 240;
    proxy_send_timeout 240;
    proxy_read_timeout 240;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9912;
}
```

Above is my nginx configuration, as I can see i'm passing Host header. Otherwise spring-boot thinks that I'm running at localhost:9912

I can say that Cloudflare pass this header correctly, not sure about AWS load balance.

Comment: thanks working for nginx+spring boot redirect to localhost issue

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a good old `UrlBasedResourceViewResolver` which creates `RedirectView` instances to handle redirect view names, then, no, Spring doesn't do anything that would cause the redirect to go to localhost.

The `RedirectView` will simply use `HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect(String)` to send the redirect. The javadoc for that says

> If the location is relative without a leading `'/'` the container
>   interprets it as relative to the current request URI

So, with a URI of

```
http://your-uri-host.com/web-app-context/whatever
```

a redirect view name like

```
redirect:survey1.do?enabled=true&page=0
```

will cause Spring to send a 302 response with a `Location` header of

```
Location: http://you-uri-host.com/web-app-context/survey1.do?enabled=true&page=0
```

There must be something else in your setup (or you user's browser) that is causing this.

Comment: The funny thing is that if it goes through the load balancer, it keeps redirecting to 'localhost' instead of the domain name. But if I directly hit the application like http://domain-name.com:8080/app/demo.do, then all the subsequent requests work fine.

Comment: The same thing happens to me, under the AWS Load Balancer, when I request "some_url", the controller of that url acceps the request, finally redirects like "redirect:https://some_domain.net". But the redirection comes to the browser like "https://localhost/some_url". The "some_url" belongs to that controller.

Comment: I see the same problem where I am behind Netflix Zuul router and using Config servers. Calls start from my Gateway service url and after redirection it becomes my internal server url in place of Gateway service url.